# Browser capabilities - check if object exists in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

What is the way to test if something exists in ClojureScript ? For instance, I am trying to access the browser geolocation API. In javascript, I would do a simple check like that :

```
// check for Geolocation support
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
}
else {
  console.log('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
}
```

But translating it to ClojureScript, I get an error :

```
(if (js/navigator.geolocation)  ;; Uncaught TypeError: navigator.geolocation is not a function
   (println "Geolocation is supported")
   (println "Geolocation is not supported"))
```

What is the proper way to check browser capabilities in ClojureScript ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is multiple options:

1. `exists?`:
   http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-495

Only exists in clojurescript and not clojure.
If you look at the macro [in core.cljc](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/04d0b92da513c8e7129e06bc34b19b1801207c32/src/main/clojure/cljs/core.cljc#L906) you'll see it's just a `if( typeof ... !== 'undefined' )`.
Example use :

```
   (if (exists? js/navigator.geolocation)
      (println "Geolocation is supported"))
      (println "Geolocation is not supported"))
```

2. `(js-in "geolocation" js/window)` which expands to `"geolocation" in windows`.
3. `(undefined? js/window.geolocation)` which expands to `void 0 === window.geolocation`

IMO, the right one is `js-in`.

Comment: I added an example use, as it was the first use of :require-macro for me. Hope that's ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I am using :

```
(if (not (nil? js/navigator.geolocation))
    (println "Geolocation is supported")
    (println "Geolocation is not supported"))
```

Not sure if this idiomatic/cover all use cases, I would gladly accept another answer with a proper explanation.